# How do I update my graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, updates

I am using a laptop and ubuntu 11.04. I would like the easiest way possible because I am new to linux.

here is my display information:

```
*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 18
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:41 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:e080(size=8)
        *-communication UNCLAIMED
             description: Communication controller
```

Comment: not an answer to your question, just suggesting that you should install VA API, real the full answer " Intel Hardware Acceleration http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

You already have the newest driver installed, as it is preinstalled by ubuntu.

You even get automatic updates.